# Are there any APIs for PCF Elastic Runtime Installation

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am trying to understand how installation of PCF on GCP can be done by [Terraforming-GCP](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/terraforming-gcp). After going through available documentation. I understood it involves 4 steps,

1. Prepare GCP env,
2. Install Ops Manager,
3. Install Bosh Director,
4. Install Elastic Runtime

AFAIK using Terraform scripts we can automate,

1. Prepare GCP env
2. Install Ops Manager

So do we have any APIs(provided by Pivotal) for Elastic Runtime? To create automated scripts for Elastic Runtime.

I searched in Pivotal docs & couldn't find them. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the Ops Manager API documentation, which is here.

https://opsman-dev-api-docs.cfapps.io/

This would allow you to script adding tiles, configuring them and ultimately starting a deployment through Ops Manager.

You may also want to look at `om`, which is a tool that wraps up the Ops Manager API and makes it easy to script actions.

https://github.com/pivotal-cf/om

Hope that helps!